# Copy from sheet2 to sheet1 based on if values match

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

The goal of this code is to iterate through a column in `sheet1` and check to see if each value matches that of values in a row in `sheet2`. If the value matches, copy 5 rows of information from `sheet2` over to `sheet1` at the specific row it is at at that moment in time.

Problems:

- Error 1004 on the first row where the if statement is.
- I think `Next b` will also throw an error

VBA code:

```
For i = 8 To 17
    For b = 7 To 21
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range(i, 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(b, 1).Value Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("b,1:b,7").Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range(i, 6)
        Next b
        End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to specify the row and column of a range as numbers, you must use `Cells` instead of `Range`. Also, your `Next b` line is throwing an error because it is inside of the nested `If` statement. Instead, you should use `Exit For` to exit the For loop, and move the `Next b` outside of the `If` statement.

```
For i = 8 To 17
    For b = 7 To 21
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(b, 1).Value Then
            Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(b, 1), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(b, 7)).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next b
Next i
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for, but not quite! What is the use of the Exit for loop?  I will post below the code i have rewritten now, which gets a 1004 runtime error